# Hope this helps

Tags: grammar, phrases

I was reply to a email that my office colleague sent just want to know a good reply to phrase "Hope this helps"

Comment: "Yes thanks" would probably do, if it did help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something along the lines of 'Thanks for the information, was really helpful', or 'Thank you, that clarified the doubts that I had' etc.

It really depends on the context in which 'Hope this helps' has been said, but in a generic sense you can use one of the replies that I mentioned above and/or modify it a little bit to suit your needs.

'Hope this helps' ;)